# grep -f is not giving any result

Tags: grep

I am trying to exclude lines from a file containing some words from another file. For example in lines.txt I have:

```
my dog
my cat
my fish
```

and in words.txt:

```
cat
```

Unfortunately, the command `grep -vif words.txt lines.txt` doesn't work, but the command `grep -vi cat lines.txt` would give me the correct result, so I guess there is a problem with the -f option. I have no idea what could be the problem with such a simple syntax, and there are no empty lines in words.txt or lines.txt, I've already checked.

Comment: I just tried 'grep -vif words.txt lines.txt' and it worked (using cygwin). What system are you using?

Comment: @DAXaholic I'm using Lubuntu 13.10 . I think you're right asking for the system because I think this command was working on the same machine a few weeks ago, but then stopped working after some upgrades maybe? Do you know any software/package that could conflict with grep?

Comment: No sorry, I don't know of any conflicting packages. But maybe there is a 'corrupt' shell alias for 'grep' in your system?

Comment: What's the output of `grep --version | head -n 1`, `which grep` and `file $(which grep)`?